# PHP trim and return a string from its right

Tags: php

I'm trying to take a string that's output from MySql like this (MySql outputs X characters):

```
$str = 'Buddy you're a boy make a big noise Playin in the stre';
```

and trying to start from the right side, trim whatever is there up till the first space. Sounded simple when I got down to it, but now, it has my brain and fingers in knots.

The output I'm tying to achieve is simple:

```
$str = 'Buddy you're a boy make a big noise Playin in the';
```

Notice, that characters starting from the right, till the first space, are removed.

Can you help?

[My Fiddle](https://eval.in/192837)

```
$str = 'Buddy you\'re a boy make a big noise Playin in the stre';

//echo rtrim($str,' ');
```

Comment: You're looking for [`strrpos`](http://php.net/strrpos) and [`substr`](http://php.net/substr), better yet a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a useful idiom to remember on its own: to remove all the characters preceding a specific one from the right side of the string (including that special character), use the following:

```
$trimmed = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, ' '));
```

... where `' '` is that special character.

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/192840)

If you don't know, however, whether or not the character is present, you'd check the result of `sttrrpos` first:

```
$last_space_index = strrpos($str, ' ');
$trimmed = $last_space_index !== false
  ? substr($str, 0, $last_space_index)
  : $str;
```

And if there can be more than one character that you need to trim, like in `'hello there      test'` line, just `rtrim` the result:

```
$trimmed = rtrim(substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, ' ')), ' ');
```

In this case, however, a regex-based solution looks more appropriate:

```
$trimmed = preg_replace('/ +[^ ]*$/', '', $str);
```

Comment: One deficiency in my view with this type of solution (I prefer regex) is that you should really trim the trailing white spaces so you can handle something like $str being `hello there      test`

Comment: @MichaelPetch You're correct, and I've added the example you mentioned. However, the point is that one has to choose the solution appropriate for their specific case. It's no good choosing more 'covering' solution just because it exists.

Comment: I think that it is reasonable to assume from the OPs post that the intention is to remove the whitespace up until the last word.

Comment: Let's ask the OP then. )

Comment: @MichaelPetch My intention is to start from the end of the string, and remove any characters upto the first space. Notice how odd the word stre looks? Thats what Im trying to get rid of. Sometimes, a string may end with an full word, but that can't be helped.

Comment: Yes I know. Let us say that there are 5 spaces before the last word. If you remove up to the first space (from the end) then you will be left with 4 extra spaces. If you intend to add something to end of the shortened line you'll probably want to remove all the white space before the last word.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option would be a regex replace:

```
preg_replace('/\s+\S*$/', '', $str);
```

which outputs `Buddy you're a boy make a big noise Playin in the`

And the [Fiddle](https://eval.in/192843)

Comment: Regex is a lot of unnecessary overload for such a simple task.

Comment: @KeVin While `regex` vs either `strrpos` or `substr` alone would be slower no doubt, using the two combined, the difference would be negligible. On a side note it's hard to find a sound `substr` vs `regex` performance comparison. Most are shaky at best.

Comment: It's about 30x slower to use regex than both of those functions combined (I just benchmarked them). The speed is negligible though for such a small task though, +1 for the flexibility of regex.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably easier to do it with regex, but I'm sooo bad with that! You shoud try this:

```
// Get all the words in an array
$strArray = explode(" ", $str);

// Remove the last word.
array_pop($strArray);

// Get it back into a sentence
$newString = implode(" ", $strArray);
```

Comment: +1 for an interesting way of handling the problem. This would also solve any `utf8` issues without using multi-byte methods.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly this approach is preferable when working with `utf8`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a hundred ways to do this, here are some options:

`array_pop`'ing the last word off an array we create from `explode`:

```
$arr = explode(" ", $str);
$fixed_arr = array_pop($arr);
$result = implode(" ", $arr);
```

Using `regular expressions`:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\s+\S*$/', '', $str);
```

and using `strrpos` and `substr`:

```
$spacePos = strrpos($str, ' ');
$result = substr($str, 0, $spacePos);
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql use

`left(field,length)`

to output only the strlen first digits

right(field,length) having opposite effects

otherwise use substr($string,0,$length) or regex in php

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of regex performance comparison, the regex engine can move faster through the string when it can perform greedy matching with minimal backtracking.

1. `/ +[^ ]*$/` uses [68 steps](https://regex101.com/r/BYUuRS/1). (@raina77ow)
2. `/(?:[^ ]+\K )+.*/` uses [56 steps](https://regex101.com/r/6Mb88P/1). (@mickmackusa)
3. `/(?:\K [^ ]*)+/` uses [48 steps](https://regex101.com/r/ZYkGaJ/1). (@mickmackusa)
4. `\s+\S*$` uses [34 steps](https://regex101.com/r/drlzm7/1). (@ChrisBornhoft and @RyanKempt)
5. `/.*\K .*/` uses [just 15 steps](https://regex101.com/r/eqG5ab/1). (@mickmackusa)

Based on these comparisons, I recommend greedily matching any characters, then restarting the fullstring match before matching the last occurring space, then matching zero or more characters until the end of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NQm5o))

```
$string = "Buddy you're a boy make a big noise Playin in the stre";
var_export(
    preg_replace('/.*\K .*/', '', $string)
);
```

Output:

```
'Buddy you\'re a boy make a big noise Playin in the'
```